# Prevent browser from trying to load favicon from root directory

Tags: html, browser, symfony4, favicon, w3c

I have a symfony route

```
    /**
     * @Route("/{connection_name}", defaults={"connection_name" ="error_mail_prod"})
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
```

And I have specified a favicon

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ asset('images/favicon.ico') }}" />
```

But it looks like the browser is still trying to load a favicon.ico from the root directory. It is requesting the route above ( https://mywebsite/favicon.ico ) with favicon.ico as an option and causing an error. 
 
My favicon is showing up properly.
Should I redefined my route ? Or is there any way to prevent the browser from trying to request a favicon at root directory even though I already specified one ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you observe is an old convention: browsers are often trying to load `/favicon.ico` no matter what.

Solutions:

- Ignore this issue. This is a perfectly reasonable solution, many sites are doing just this.
- Make `/favicon.ico` available (add the file, define the route...) to prevent avoidable 404 errors in your logs.

Comment: Even if I add it to root directory, it's still not accessible from outside, it seems webpack doesn't copy images from the root, they have to be inside assets